# Error when running NBTree and Random forest through Weka, Java

Tags: java, weka, random-forest

I am implementing the combination of NBTree and Random forest through product rule. My code is working fine as long as I use same dataset for training and testing but I receive error when I use a new dataset for testing. This is the implementation.

```
RandomForest objRandomForest = new RandomForest();
Classifier[] objClassifiers = {objNBTree,objRandomForest};
objVote.setClassifiers(objClassifiers);

System.out.println("=== Building Model ===");

objVote.buildClassifier(train);

Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(test);
eval.evaluateModel(objVote, test);

System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n===============\n", true));
```

The dataset contains many attributes with numeric values therefore I also discretized them too and following is the code

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("C:/Users/MUHAMMAD GALA/Documents/CN/Project/NSL_KDD-master/test1000b.arff"));
Instances data = new Instances(reader);

String[] options = new String[2];
options[0] = "-R";
options[1] = "First-last";
Discretize d = new Discretize();
d.setOptions(options);
d.setInputFormat(data);
Instances newData = Filter.useFilter(data, d);

ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
saver.setInstances(newData);
saver.setFile(new File("C:/Users/MUHAMMAD GALA/Documents/CN/Project/NSL_KDD-master/test1000c.arff"));
saver.writeBatch();
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12
at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.NBTreeNoSplit.classProb(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.ClassifierTree.getProbs(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.ClassifierTree.getProbs(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.ClassifierTree.distributionForInstance(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.trees.NBTree.distributionForInstance(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.meta.Vote.distributionForInstanceProduct(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.meta.Vote.distributionForInstance(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModelOnceAndRecordPrediction(Unknown Source)
at weka.classifiers.Evaluation.evaluateModel(Unknown Source)
at combinationkitesting.CombinationKiTesting.MajorityVotePrediction(CombinationKiTesting.java:88)
at combinationkitesting.CombinationKiTesting.main(CombinationKiTesting.java:54)
```